# Universal method for getting absolute path (elastic in case of classpath and absolute path)

Tags: java, properties

In my properties I have property:

```
path=...
```

In my app I must evaluate absolute path of `path`. I would like to universal code which does it. Is it possible?
I mean something like:

```
@Value(${path})
private void setAbsolutePath(String path){
    absolutePath = elastic(path);  
}
```

`elastic` should deal with path in resources, like:
`path=/config/my.cfg`   (here I am confused, maybe it should be `classpath:/config/my.cfg`)
`path=C:\\config\\my.cfg`